A question regarding Coulomb sum in two dimension
The following arguments can be found in texts about Laughlin's wavefunction and theta function such as Laughlin's paper "Spin hamiltonian for which quantum hall wavefunction is exact". It is known that the solution to Poisson's equation $-\nabla^2\phi(r)=\delta(r)$ in two dimension is $\phi(r)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln r$. And the solution corresponding to a 2d ball with uniform charge density $\rho$ is $\phi(r)=-\frac{1}{4}\rho r^2$ inside the ball.
Now consider a lattice $(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers. Suppose there is a unit charge on each lattice. Let $z=x+yi$. Consider the following sum:
$$F(z)=\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\bigg(-\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{|z_0|<R}\ln|z-z_0|+\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{0<|z_0|<R}\ln|z_0|\bigg)$$
where $z_0$ are only summed over lattice sites. This means the difference between the potential produced by a lattice at $z$ and the potential at the center if the charge at center is missing. The limit means we first calculate the result for charges on lattice sites inside a large enough ball, then make its radius go to infinity.
$F(z)$ for large $z$ contains two parts: the long range contribution which equals the potential inside a ball with averaged charge density, $-\frac{1}{4}|z|^2$, and the short range periodic variation, $P(z)=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}(-\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{|z-z_0|<R}\ln|z-z_0|+\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{0<|z_0|<R}\ln|z_0|)$. (Note that the first term is summed over lattice sites in a ball centered at z rather than origin) Thus
$$F(z)=-\frac{1}{4}|z|^2+P(z)$$
Now there seems to be a contradiction. Since $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\ln|z|=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\ln z=\frac{1}{2z}$, both $\frac{\partial F(z)}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial P(z)}{\partial z}$ should be holomorphic where they are defined. But from the above equation this can't be the case since $\frac{\partial |z|^2}{\partial z}=z^*$.

It seems like you are trying to compute the Madelung constant. Google searching Coulomb sum would be difficult to get good results. Those $\ln|z|$ probably isn't meant to have absolute values; in a lattice sum you probably should have pairs or triplets of lattice points cancelling out their angular phase contributions, so these can be standard radial logarithms. Note that, despite many textbooks covering so, the Madelung constant does not converge if summed spherically (not sure of your 2D analogue), but converges as a cubic lattice. You might want to check that.

@naturallyInconsistent Here, F(z) is the potential at z relative to the potential at origin when the charge at origin is absent, I think that can be well defined even if two sums diverge individually. Maybe I should edit my question to specify that the limit of R to infinity is taken simultaneously.

@naturallyInconsistent Sorry, now I get your point. The subtracted part can be viewed as another sub-lattice of negative charges centered at z. This indeed might not be convergent. I will look into it.

The physics means that it must converge to something sensible. It is just that what is going to mathematically provably converge is not exactly obvious. Sometimes it is just about trying.
